# Changing the size of the lamp reflected from the water surface

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

[image]

Have you noticed that the image reflected from the water surface with ripples differs in size from the initial one?

From the image you can see that it’s reflect some times.

Moreover from basic optical principals I got that the image should lengthen.

Let’s say that the ange of ripples changes from -30 degree to 30 degree from the horizontal(perhaps we can assume that the wave has the sine shape but I’m not sure). All geometric parameters are also known (heigh of source, horizontal length to source, source’s size (let it be disk)).

How to predict the final shape (size) of image? Ideally, we are interested in finding the parameters of the curve around the image.

Comment: You probably should clarify how this question differs from: ["Why do reflections on a rough surface stretch from the light source towards you instead of spreading out in all directions?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/431708/145491), ["Why does sunset over a body of water cause a path of light stretching towards the horizon?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110820/145491), and [Long, blurry reflections in wet road](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185072/145491).