# Why is frosted glass reflective at an angle?

Tags: optics, reflection, glass

I have a Pixel 3, and the back of the phone is frosted glass. I noticed today that if I look at the back from a wide angle it becomes reflective, whereas it is opaque when looking directly on.

What causes this phenomenon?

Comment: [Why is there a clear mirror image off a rough surface at shallow angles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350226/why-is-there-a-clear-mirror-image-off-a-rough-surface-at-shallow-angles). [Why does light reflect more intensely when it hits a surface at a large angle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12035/85443). The Answers are a bit opaque to me - this might be a "need to do the math" situation. Is the surface etched clear glass (possibly with a transparent coating) or milky glass like Corelle dinnerware?

Comment: That basically answers my question. Do you want to post that comment as a reply and I'll mark as solved?

Comment: Thanks, but links to other answers would not qualify as an answer here.

Comment: No problem, I flagged my own post as duplicate