# Moonlight reflection on ocean

Tags: optics, visible-light, astronomy, water, reflection

I am trying to explain physically what is happening in the picture below:

[image]

My gut explanation is that we are observing the reflection of a cone of light emanating from the moon, it explains the form of this reflection which looks like a cross section of a cone but I'm not convinced with this explanation.

I know this is supposed to be easy but, it bugs that I am not able to have an answer. Do you have a more convincing physics explanation?

Comment: Related [Why does sunset over a body of water cause a path of light stretching towards the horizon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110820/why-does-sunset-over-a-body-of-water-cause-a-path-of-light-stretching-towards-th)

Comment: Related but brief:: https://www.quora.com/Optics-When-you-see-the-sun-or-the-moon-reflected-in-a-body-of-water-why-is-the-reflection-a-stripe-and-not-a-circle